# RAMdisk slower than disk?

Tags: performance, file, ramdisk

A python program I created is IO bounded. The majority of the time (over 90%) is spent in a single loop which repeats ~10,000 times. In this loop, ~100KB data is generated and written to a temporary file; it is then read back out by another program and statistics about that data collected. This is the only way to pass data into the second program.

Due to this being the main bottleneck, I thought that moving the location of the temporary file from my main HDD to a (~40MB) RAMdisk (inside of over 2GB of free RAM) would greatly increase the IO speed for this file and so reduce the run-time. However, I obtained the following results (each averaged over 20 runs):

- Test data 1: Without RAMdisk - 72.7s, With RAMdisk - 78.6s
- Test data 2: Without RAMdisk - 223.0s, With RAMdisk - 235.1s

It would appear that the RAMdisk is slower that my HDD.

What could be causing this?

Are there any other alternative to using a RAMdisk in order to get faster file IO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operating system is almost certainly buffering/caching disk writes already.  It's not surprising the RAM disk is so close in performance.

Without knowing exactly what you're writing or how, we can only offer general suggestions.  Some ideas:

- If you have 2 GB RAM you probably have a decent processor, so you could write this data to a filesystem that has compression.  That would trade I/O operations for CPU time, assuming your data is amenable to that.
- If you're doing many small writes, combine them to write larger pieces at once.  (Can we see the source code?)
- Are you removing the 100 KB file after use?  If you don't need it, then delete it.  Otherwise the OS may be forced to flush it to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Can you write the data out in batches rather than one item at a time? Are you caching resources like open file handles etc or cleaning those up? Are your disk writes blocking, can you use background threads to saturate IO while not affecting compute performance.

I would look at optimising the disk writes first, and then look at faster disks when that is complete.

Comment: The point is that he's now using pure RAM - not even a disk at all. By all expectations, he should be getting better performance than even the fastest SSD's on the market would give - yet it's slower than a mechanical drive. He's asking why that might be the case.

Comment: Yes I appreciate that. I was suggesting that maybe its not the disk rather the way the disks are used that's the problem.

Comment: Arafangion: The idea that "RAM = electronic, disk = mechanical" isn't really true any more.  Your OS is welcome to copy memory pages to disk when it needs to (RAM -> mechanical), or cache files in memory if it wants to (disk -> electronic).  Dirty pages (code, data, or files) only get flushed to a mechanical platter when it needs that RAM for something.

Answer (score 2):

I know that Windows is very aggressive about caching disk data in RAM, and 100K would fit easily. The writes are going directly to cache and then perhaps being written to disk via a non-blocking write, which allows the program to continue. The RAM disk probably wouldn't support non-blocking operations because it expects those operations to be quick and not worth the bother.

By reducing the amount of memory available to programs and caching, you're going to increase the amount of disk I/O for paging even if only slightly.

This is all speculation on my part, since I'm not familiar with the kernel or drivers. I also speculate that Linux would operate similarly.

Answer (score 1):

In my tests I've found that not only batch size affects overall performance, but also the nature of data itself. I've managed to get 5 times better write times compared to SSD in only one scenario: writing a 100MB chunk of pre-cooked random byte array to RAM drive. Writing more "predictable" data like letters "aaa" or current datetime yields quite opposite results - SSD is always faster or equal. So my guess is that opertating system (Win 7 in my case) does lots of caching and optimizations. 
Looks like the most hindering case for RAM-drive is when you perform lots of small writes instead of a few big ones, and RAM drive shines at writing large amounts of hard-to-compress data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mind boggling experience, and after many tries I figured it out.
When ramdisk is formatted as FAT32, then even though benchmarks shows high values, real world use is actually slower than NTFS formatted SSD. 
But NTFS formatted ramdisk is faster in real life than SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I join the people having problems with RAM disk speeds (only on Windows).

The SSD i have can write 30 GiB (in one big block, dump a 30GiB RAM ARRAY) with a speed of 550 MiB/s (arround 56 seconds to write 30 GiB) ... this is if the write is asked in one source code sentence.

The RAM Disk (imDisk) i have can write 30 GiB write (in one big block, dump a 30GiB RAM ARRAY) with a speed of a bit less than 100 MiB/s (arround 5 minutes and 13 seconds to write 30 GiB) ... this is if the write is asked in one source code sentence.

I had also done another RAM test: from source code do a sequential direct write (one byte per source code loop pass) to a 30GiB RAM ARRAY (i have 64GiB of RAM) and i get a speed of near 1.3GiB/s (1298 MiB per second).

Why on the hell (on Windows) RAM Disk is so slow for one BIG secuential write?

Of course that low write speed happens on RAM disks on Windows, since i tested the same 'concept' on Linux with Linux native ram disk and Linux ram disk can write at near one gigabyte per second.

Please note that i had also tested SoftPerfect and other RAM disks on Windows, RAM Disk speeds are near the same, can not write at more than one hundred megabytes per second.

Actual Windows tested: 10 & 11 (on both HOME & PRO, on 64 bits), RAM Disk format (exFAT & NTFS); since RAM disk speed was too slow i was trying to find one Windows version where RAM disk speed be normal, but found no one.
Actual Linux Kernel tested: Only 5.15.11, since Linux native RAM disk speed was normal i do not test on any other kernel.

Hope this help other people, since knowledge is the base to solve a problem.