# Use RAM with gradle and IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, ramdrive

Currently, I'm using gradle as our production java builder and it's slow.

I was thinking is there a way to set-up some kind of RAMdrive working directory, so compiling, building, testing, and running would be much faster and the source code would remain on HDD.

Ideally, if I could tune it in my IDE somehow (maybe IDE internal gradle options).

I have initialized a RAMdrive but stuck in gradle :) Any ideas?

Comment: BTW my OS is Windows :)

Comment: Have you actually measured that you need a faster drive? From my experience, the CPU is a bottleneck for compiling if you have an SSD. Have you excluded everything from the antivirus? That makes a huge difference.

Comment: I have actually tested with whole project in RAM and CPU is actually the bottleneck, but i'm still curious about this topic and working with RamDrive would still be faster. And i don't have an SSD.

Comment: Well considering that SSD can speed up your compiling like ~3x, then, of course, Ramdisk would do the same. It may be tricky though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929096/ramdisk-slower-than-disk
Buy a good SSD, it's the best upgrade you can have.

Comment: Syntetic tests like that usually don't give an accurate picture. And buying SSD is not an option right now, so i want to speed-up with what i have.